# Converting Char value to money for concatenated variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure which was working fine until I had to introduce @n variable to change the procedure for new requirements.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_insertValue]  
   ,@p1001          varchar(18)
   ,@p1002          varchar(18)
   ,@p1003          varchar(18)   
as
begin
  declare @i varchar(25) 
  declare @n varchar(25) 
  declare @limit int 

  set @limit = 1004;
  set @i = 1001;

  while (@i <=@limit)
  begin
     set @n = '@'+p'+@i;
     if(@n is not null)
     begin
        if EXISTS (select Id  from t_values where Id=@i)
        begin
           update t_values 
           set  amount    =convert(varchar,cast(@n as money),2)
           where Id =@i 
        end
     end 

     set @i=@i+1;
  end  
end
```

When I run the procedure it returns an error

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

Basically problem is with this line

```
 set @n = '@'+'p'+@i;
```

as the while loops through this is suppose to be @p1001, @p1002, @p1003 so its values can be converted to money. It works fine when i try with direct @p1001 etc.

Please let me know how to correct this line so it can work properly.

Comment: erm, what on earth is that supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to set @n=@p1001 , @n=@p1002, @n=@p1003 as the while loops through.

Comment: Why is `@limit` set twice? Even if the syntax worked setting it to `1026` means you would need values for up to and including `@p1026`. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Actually in my code it goes to 1026 but i didnt wana write all that extra code so set it to 1004 instead. MSSQL 2008.

Comment: So you should replace the whole thing with a table valued parameter mapping `id -> amount` that contains 26 rows. Also why are you passing `money` values in as `varchar(18)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a variable by constructing a string of its name as you are attempting.

As Mitch says this is pretty horrible anyway though.

- If `@p1001` are supposed to contain `money` values then use `money` datatype instead of `varchar(18)`
- And why do you cast it to `money` then back to varchar in the `SET`
- Why are you declaring `@i` as `varchar(25)` instead of integer?
- Instead of passing in parameter values `@p1001` to `@p1026` individually and adding new parameters every time you need to extend the list just pass in a table valued parameter.
- You are processing row by row instead of set based.
- The incrementing `where Id =@i` clause looks extremely suspect as `IDENTITY` values are not guaranteed sequential.

The quickest way of fixing this whilst preserving the highly questionable semantics would be to just replace the whole thing with

```
UPDATE T
SET    amount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), cast(V.amount AS MONEY), 2)
FROM   t_values T
       JOIN (VALUES('1001', @p1001),
                   ('1002', @p1002),
                   ('1003', @p1003)) V(Id, amount)
         ON V.Id = T.Id
```

If you can rewrite the whole thing then replace the `VALUES` clause with a TVP with two columns of the correct datatype.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for the pointers. I changed it accordingly and worked great. Thanks again.